# Code to Highlight text matching pattern

Tags: php

I use this function to highlight fields in my search results, 
looking for feedback on it.

```
// Example usage 
$pattern = 'shut inw';
$haystack = 'Courtesy Shuttle Inwards';

$output = HtmlUtils::hilite($haystack, $needle);

$output is html and will contain
Courtesy <span class="hilite">Shut</span>tle <span class="hilite">Inw</span>ards


class HtmlUtils
{

    /**
     * @param string $haystack
     * @param string $needle
     * @param string $class
     * @return string
     */
    public static function hilite($haystack, $needle, $class = 'hilite')
    {
        $haystack = htmlentities($haystack);
        $needle = htmlentities($needle);

        if ($needle) {
            $needle = StringUtils::compactSpaces($needle);
            $needles = explode(' ', $needle);

            $escaped_needles = [];
            foreach ($needles as $needle) {
                $escaped_needles[] = preg_quote($needle, '/');
            }

            $escaped_needles = join('|', $escaped_needles);
            $highlighted_text = preg_replace_callback("/({$escaped_needles})/i",
                function ($matches) use ($class) {
                    return "<span class='". $class . "'>" . $matches[0] . "</span>";
                },
                $haystack
            );
        } else {
            $highlighted_text = $haystack;
        }

        return $highlighted_text;
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the supporting functions

```
    public static function compactSpaces($str)
    {
        return preg_replace('/\s\s+/u', ' ', $str);
    }

   /**
     * @param string $haystack
     * @param string[] $needles
     * @return array
     */
    public static function findFirstMatch($haystack, array $needles)
    {
        $min_pos = false;
        $matching_needle = null;

        $needles = self::sortByLengthDesc($needles);

        foreach ($needles as $needle) {
            $pos = mb_stripos($haystack, $needle);
            if ($pos !== false) {
                if ($min_pos === false || $pos < $min_pos) {
                    $min_pos = $pos;
                    $matching_needle = $needle;
                }
            }
        }

        return [
            'pos' => $min_pos,
            'needle' => $matching_needle,
        ];
    }


    /**
     * @param string[] $strings
     * @return string[]
     */
    public static function sortByLengthDesc($strings)
    {
        usort($strings, function($a, $b) {
            if ($a == $b) {
                return 0;
            }

            $diff = (mb_strlen($b) - mb_strlen($a));

            // same length, lets go with alphabetical
            if ($diff == 0) {
                return strcasecmp($a, $b);
            }

            return $diff;
        });

        return $strings;
    }
```

Here are the unit tests I wrote for it

```
public function testHiliteMatch()
{
    $haystack = 'test string';
    $needle = 'Test';
    $class = 'test';
    $expected = '<span class="test">test</span> string';

    $actual = HtmlUtils::hilite($haystack, $needle, $class);

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}


public function testHiliteNoMatch()
{
    $haystack = 'test string';
    $needle = 'invalid';
    $class = 'test';
    $expected = 'test string';

    $actual = HtmlUtils::hilite($haystack, $needle, $class);

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}


public function testHiliteHtmlEntity()
{
    $haystack = 'test& <string';
    $needle = 'test&';
    $expected = '<span class="hilite">test&amp;</span> &lt;string';

    $actual = HtmlUtils::hilite($haystack, $needle);

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}


public function testHiliteHtmlEntityAmp()
{
    $haystack = 'I am here & there';
    $needle = 'am';
    $expected = 'I <span class="hilite">am</span> here &amp; there';

    $actual = HtmlUtils::hilite($haystack, $needle);

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}
```

Added additional test based on feedback from @Dereckson

```
public function testHiliteZeroString()
{
    $haystack = '1234567890';
    $needle = '0';
    $expected = '123456789<span class="hilite">0</span>';

    $actual = HtmlUtils::hilite($haystack, $needle);

    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}
```

Based on feedback from @Roland Illig, this is the updated version

```
/**
 * @param string $haystack
 * @param string $needle
 * @param string $class
 * @return string
 */
public static function hilite($haystack, $needle, $class = 'hilite')
{
    $haystack = $haystack;
    $needle = $needle;

    $needle = StringUtils::compactSpaces($needle);

    if ($needle === '' || $needle === null) {
        return $haystack;
    }

    $needles = explode(' ', $needle);

    $output = '';

    while (strlen($haystack) > 0) {
        $match = StringUtils::findFirstMatch($haystack, $needles);

        if ($match['pos'] === false) {
            // no matches, exit loop
            $output .= htmlentities($haystack);
            break;
        }

        // grab the bit before the match, and html escape it
        $output .= htmlentities(mb_substr($haystack, 0, $match['pos']));

        // hilite the matching needle
        $matching_text = mb_substr($haystack, $match['pos'], mb_strlen($match['needle']));
        $output .= '<span class="' . $class . '">' . htmlentities($matching_text) . "</span>";

        // grab the bit after the matching needle and test again
        $haystack = mb_substr($haystack, $match['pos'] + mb_strlen($matching_text));
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Unit tests added

Comment: I did try to rewrite it using regex, but it became too complex, and it raised other issues, eg what order should I match the needles in, I have chosen longest to shortest. Would still be interested in your opinion.

Comment: Looks good to me now.

Comment: If $needle is the "0" string, it won't hl it, as "0" will be converted into the 0 integer then the false boolean in your if ($needle) condition.

Comment: @Dereckson good spotting. I have added an extra test and altered the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These first two lines are a waste of space:

```
$haystack = $haystack;
$needle = $needle;
```

Just remove them.

---

If you don't trust the user to provide clean, single-spaced substrings in `$needle`, then replace your `compactSpaces()` & `explode()` portion with:

```
preg_split('/\s+/',$needle,NULL,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

This will not just generate the desired array of space-free elements; it will ensure that there are no empty elements even if there are leading or trailing spaces on the `$needle` string.

Just for the sake of discussing your original pattern, I don't see the need to write the unicode modifier in `compactSpaces()` and I would use a different syntax. `/\s\s+/u` could/should be `/\s{2,}/` not that it improves performance -- I just think it reads more logically.

Finally, if you wanted to entertain a funky approach, you could use `str_word_count()` to generate the array.  This is potentially less trustworthy depending on the expected language of input and where you end the ranged character list (3rd parameter). `!`([exclamation mark](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0021)) is the first character after (space) and I'll demonstrate using the arbitrary range end character `Ϳ`([Greek Capital Letter Yot](https://unicode-table.com/en/#037F)) it is a fair way down the character list.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4443380595909288d697a6e1539215c1fc05871f))

```
str_word_count($needle,1,'!..Ϳ')
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Ɖiamoŋd\'Ș',
  1 => 'a®e',
  2 => 'ɑ',
  3 => 'girl\'s',
  4 => 'best',
  5 => 'fɌiend.',
)
```

---

It is important to mitigate the effect of smaller needle substrings existing inside larger needle substrings.  I think you have ironed this out in recent edits.

`strtr()` has this innate "special power" but unfortunately the function doesn't have a case-insensitive version.

Because there is no word boundaries included in this function, regex functions should be avoided. (you have also edit your code to fix this)  The simplicity of `preg_replace_callback()` will cost efficiency, and I don't think that is the point of this task.

---

Because you are writing:

```
while (strlen($haystack) > 0) {
    $match = findFirstMatch($haystack, $needles);
```

You are calling `findFirstMatch()` up to **[number of matches]+1** times.  This should only be done once -- take the call outside the loop.

In fact, I'd say just apply the `usort()` normally.  Not set the new sorted array to a variable.  (I'll show what I mean when I post my suggested code.)

---

Regarding multibyte functions, it is important that you realize the serious drag that all `mb_` functions have versus their non-multibyte equivalent.  See the benchmark comments below [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php).  For this reason, it would be reasonable to build another parameter into `hilite()` that asks `isMultiByte` and fork the process from the beginning.  If forking the function was not desired and this was my project, I would think seriously about whether their is any actual benefit to `usort()`ing with `mb_strlen()` versus `strlen()`.  My gut feeling is that measuring with multibyte accuracy is not worth the cost.  I am happy to <s>strikeout</s> this claim if anyone can demonstrate otherwise.

Here is what I've been toying with: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b89c7c10b1a413ce81524f2a66a66f9f6a94116f))

```
function hilite($haystack, $needle, $class='hilite'){
    $needles=preg_split('/\s+/', $needle, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);  // clean explode, pluralize variable name
    if(!sizeof($needles)){ return $haystack; }  // nothing to search with, quick return

    // prepare the needles
    $needles=array_flip(array_flip($needles));  // remove duplicates faster than array_unique()
    usort($needles,function($a, $b){return strlen($b) <=> strlen($a);});  // sort by DESC length one time    

    $output = ''; // initialize
    while(strlen($haystack)){  // no > comparison needed
        $min_pos=NULL;  // unique default value for post-foreach check
        foreach($needles as $needle){
            if(($pos=mb_stripos($haystack,$needle))!==false && (is_null($min_pos) || $pos<$min_pos)){  // found & (1st | lower)
                $min_pos=$pos;
                $match=$needle;
                if($pos===0){break;} // end foreach because zero cannot be beaten
            }
        } 

        if(is_null($min_pos)){
            return $output .= htmlentities($haystack); // no more matches, quick return
        }

        if($min_pos>0){  // spare two needless function calls if ===0
            $output .= htmlentities(mb_substr($haystack, 0, $min_pos));  // concat pre-match substring to output
        }

        $matching_text = mb_substr($haystack, $min_pos, mb_strlen($match));
        $output .= '<span class="'.$class.'">'.htmlentities($matching_text).'</span>';  // concat match to output

        $haystack = mb_substr($haystack, $min_pos + mb_strlen($matching_text));  // trim match from left side of haystack
    }
    return $output;
}
```

p.s. When all of the dust settles and you are happy with your finished non-regex method, you should compare it to your leanest version using `preg_replace_callback()` just to see if all this messing around is actually worth it!

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a read thru in the morning

Comment: for the record, I've just refined my suggested code block to simplify the `while()` portion.

Comment: Thanks for your review. quick question, should this bit while(strlen($haystack)) be using mb_strlen()

Comment: No, I've intentionally left out the `mb_` there and on the `usort` call.  At these calls, there is no benefit to measuring the multibyte length.  `mb_` functions are more expensive versus their non-multibyte versions. This was a design decision based on efficiency.

Comment: cheers, i just thought i would check incase it was an oversight

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not handle the following call correctly:

```
hilite("I am here & there", "am");
```

This is because the `am` is part of the `&amp;`.

I rewrote your code in Java (since I don't have PHP installed), and now it works for me:

```
public static String hilite(String haystack, String needle, String cssClass) {
    if (needle.isEmpty()) {
        return htmlentities(haystack);
    }

    List<String> escapedNeedles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String needleWord : needle.split("\\s+")) {
        escapedNeedles.add(Pattern.quote(needleWord));
    }
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.join("|", escapedNeedles), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(haystack);

    while (m.find()) {
        // escape and append the part before the match
        StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
        m.appendReplacement(tmp, "");
        sb.append(htmlentities(tmp.toString()));

        // escape and append the match
        sb.append("<span class='" + htmlentities(cssClass) + "'>" + htmlentities(m.group()) + "</span>");
    }

    // escape and append the part after the last match
    StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
    m.appendTail(tmp);
    sb.append(htmlentities(tmp.toString()));

    return sb.toString();
}
```

The basic idea is to only do the HTML escaping when adding parts to the result string. All search operations take place on the plain strings.

Translating this code back to PHP is not easy since PHP doesn't have the `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` methods. Therefore you probably have to fiddle with the offsets where the needles are found. Calling `preg_match_all` with the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag could work.

Note that although Java provides a way to solve this task, I used `appendReplacement` in a creative way by always giving it a fresh `StringBuffer`. This is not the normal way. Nevertheless, it works.

Comment: Good catch, I will have a look thru and see if I can figure out how to do it in php. thanks

Comment: I have had another go at it, and added the updated code to my question.  If you could take another look that would be appreciated.

Comment: If you wanted to use PHP you could use a site like phpfiddle.org, ideone.com, tehplayground.com, etc...